# Выделенние компонент адреса в результатах suggest

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

В API есть функция suggest, возвращающая набор подсказок. Подсказки это по сути строки.

Есть/будет ли возможность выделять из строк отдельные компоненты : город, страна, дом, улица? 
Это было бы удобно для автозапонения форм, где адрес разбит на поля.

Comment: Спасибо за фичреквест, сейчас такой возможности нет: адрес разбит на компоненты только в ответе геокодера

Comment: suggest - только в строковом виде и только для подсказок, геокодер - непосредственно для поиска адреса и его сопоставления с координатами на карте. Думаю, лучше для ввода адреса использовать общее поле, а уже после геокодирования разбивать адрес на компаненты.
есть такой пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/input_validation

Comment: Просто есть задача сделать такую форму как [тут](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform?hl=ru), только чтобы заполнять можно было отдельные поля: страну, потом город и т д. Логика получается такая что при заполнении каждого из последующих полей конкатенировать все предыдущие и показывать подсказку по нему, на промежуточных этапах делать геокодирование.

Comment: так вы рискуете очень быстро превысить лимит бесплатного использования геокодера, что приведет к автоматической блокировке сервиса на остаток суток, а при частых превышениях и насовсем (= до перехода на коммерческую лицензию)

Comment: Тут даже вопрос в другом. А геокодер будет ли выдавать ответы если адрес не указан с точностью до дома?

Comment: да, прогеокодировать можно страну, город, регион или улицу. Для этого есть разные значения kind

Comment: Но тут палка о двух концах, мы от геокодера хотим узнать каждый  из компонент, но для того чтобы узнать мы должны указать что мы хотим узнать.